# Hibernate "PostUpdateEventListener" onPostUpdate and Callback method "PostUpdate" calling wrongly

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and Spring Data JPA 1.9.4 with MS Sql server2014 database.

```
I have one table with entity Book and table as below.

@Table(name="Book")
@Entity
@EntityListeners (HibernateListener.class)
public class Book{ 
    @Column(name="ID", nullable=false)
    @Id private Integer id;
     
    @Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
    private String name;
   //getters and setters
}


public class HibernateListener{
    /**
     * automatic property set before any database persistence
     */
    @PostUpdate
    public void postUpdate(Cat o) {
      System.out.println("Post update")
    }
}
```

As per the requirement i need to do some operations after update object i.e  post updation of cat object only. so i added HibernateListener and added one method postupdate with annotation of @PostUpdate. But this call back method calling on every time with & with out updation of cat object by using JPA saveandflush(cat) method.

Is any thing missed from my side to restrict to calling this call back method only when updates happens on cat object?

For time being i tried in different way to solve above problem.

I tried to create new class by implements the PostUpdateEventListner method override onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) and register this listener while start the spring boot. But this overrided method also  onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) calling on every time with & with out updation of cat object by using JPA saveandflush(cat) methtod.

Please suggest good way to restrict to calling this call back method only when updates happens on cat object?